# Unity3D spawning 2d objects at fixed locations

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an object that when clicked it is destroyed and spawns randomly somewhere else on a timer. I'm trying to make it so instead of random spots it shows up at fixed locations.

I also want them to randomly spawn at those fixed locations on a timed interval, one at a time.(so if it appears in one location for lets say 5 seconds, it will be destroyed and the next one will appear in a different location.)

I attempted to do fixed spawn locations, but the void spawner doesn't want to work.

I get a "The object of type "GameObject" has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it".

I can fix this by commenting out the On_TouchStart destroy line, but I need it.

Here is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public float AppearTime = 0f;
    public Transform[] teleport;
    public GameObject[] prefab;

    void Spawner(){ 
        int tele_num = Random.Range(0,5);
        int prefab_num = Random.Range(0,3);
        if (prefab !=null){
        Instantiate(prefab[prefab_num], teleport[tele_num].position, teleport[tele_num].rotation );
        }
    }


    void StartTime()
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoTime());

    }

    void OnEnable(){
        EasyTouch.On_TouchStart += On_TouchStart;
    }

    IEnumerator DoTime()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(AppearTime);
        Spawner();

    }

    void On_TouchStart (Gesture gesture){

        if (gesture.pickObject != null){
            Destroy(gesture.pickObject);
            StartTime();
        }
    }
```

If anyone could lead me on the right track I'd appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there a particular thing you're struggling with? It's not clear what the problem is with the code you've posted, or if/how you've tried to fix it.

Comment: I created the void spawner to make my objects spawn at fixed points. It doesn't work however, i'll update my question to be more clear.

Comment: "It doesn't work" <-- what doesn't work? Are they not spawned? Are they simply left at 0,0,0? This could mean anything.

Comment: Nothing happens. On play when I click to attempt spawning, I get the error message stated above.

Comment: What type is pickObject?

Comment: It's a GameObject type. It allows touch recognition for my objects.

Comment: If only get that error if you have a reference to a destroyed object. By looking at this code, the only way to get that error message would be if the object you destroy is one of the object you try to use when you instantiate. If thats the case, you also need to remove it from the list when it is destroyed.

Comment: When doing that I noticed I just got another error stating "IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index out of range". And it references to my Instantiate.

Comment: Thats because you have hard coded the length of the array when you pick an index, change Random.Range(0,5) to Random.Range(0,teleport.Length) and Random.Range(0,prefab_num.Length)

Comment: Well at the very least that makes it so I can have an infinite amount of spawners and objects, but that doesn't fix my array. I still get an "Index is out of range" error(On play.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out the prefabs I were using were incorrect, so I needed to swap them out for ones that did.
Thanks to the ones who helped.